# What's the best way to handle reconnection with MqttPahoMessageHandler as token has now expired?

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

I have used the following example as a basis for my own code to publish to a MQTT server: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/mqtt/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/mqtt/Application.java

I have a particular use case where the password is a token in particular a keycloak token which will expire. If for whatever reason the spring application loses connection with the MQTT server and tries to reconnect the token will have expired and an MqttSecurityException: Not authorized to connect exception will be thrown. I tried extending the method connectionLost in MqttPahoMessageHandler but as the MqttPahoClientFactory & IMqttAsyncClient are private final there is not much I can do. Wondering if there is any other approach I've not thought of or is the library just not meant to be used like this???

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

We get the `MqttConnectOptions` from [the client factory each time we try to connect](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/1511dd8748dbb72077111144f8460d97fc5068d2/spring-integration-mqtt/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mqtt/outbound/MqttPahoMessageHandler.java#L190) so you should be able to just update the password there.

If that doesn't work for some reason, open a [new feature request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues).

**EDIT**

Regarding your comment, what's wrong with this?

```java
    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" });
        options.setUserName("guest");
        options.setPassword("guest".toCharArray());
        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory, MqttPahoMessageHandler handler) {
        return args -> {
            Thread.sleep(30_000);
            System.out.println("Changing password");
            mqttClientFactory.getConnectionOptions().setPassword("foo".toCharArray());
            handler.stop();
            handler.start();
        };
    }
```

```
foo
2020-03-10 17:42:33.560  INFO 95638 --- [iSampleConsumer] siSample                                 
  : foo sent to MQTT, received from MQTT
Changing password
foo
2020-03-10 17:43:08.705 ERROR 95638 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   
  : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'mqttOutbound' for component 'mqttOutFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'; defined in: 'com.example.demo.So60610337Application'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.StandardMethodMetadata@79da8dc5']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to connect; nested exception is Bad user name or password (4), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=foo sent to MQTT, headers={id=4eab5b52-726f-7ea3-252d-77c4d0401cc8, timestamp=1583876588662}]
...
Caused by: Bad user name or password (4)
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue is because I'm using DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory as a bean. Once the password is set inside the bean there doesn't seem to be a place I can update the password in MqttConnectOptions on lose of connection. I'll raise a feature request....

Comment: I don't understand - it works fine for me; see the edit to my answer. Do you mean you don't know when the connection is lost? If you also have an inbound adapter, you can listen for a `MqttConnectionFailedEvent`; we should probably publish such an event when the connection is lost on the producer side too.

Comment: yeah the solution you put forward doesn't really solve my issue.

Comment: I want to be able to be retrieve a new token, and reconnect to the MQTT server when the connection is lost between the application & mqtt. I added a listener for the MqttConnectionFailedEvent & created my own implementation of MqttPahoMessageHandler adding the publishEvent code into connectionLost like seen in MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter. Then the listener just retrieves a new token and restarts the MessageHandler.

Comment: Great; please consider submitting a PR for the event publication.